# Difference between series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Is it in general true the following equality?
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \pi_n-\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n \pi_n =
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (a_n-b_n) \pi_n
\end{equation*}
If the answer is no (as I'm suspecting right now), what conditions we must request on the terms $a_n,b_n,\pi_n$?

Comment: If any two of the three series converge, then the equation holds.